# What are the actions that trigger comment notifications?

Tags: support, comments, notifications

I've read some related questions about comment notifications, but I have not found anything mentioned all of the scenarios that trigger a notification.

I have been amazed that I have not seen any non-related comment notifications so far in SO, which is why I'm curious about how they work so well.

For example if I post a comment to a question, I'll get notification if the OP post a comment, even if s/he didn't mention me. but I won't get notifications for other comments (of course if I don't add any more comments).

How does the system detect when to send notifications? What are the parameters?

Comment: Cross site duplicate of [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/369403)

Comment: "but I didn't get any more notification for other comments (if I didn't add more comments)" ... this has nothing to do with how many comments you write. If there are more comments from different users, when you obviously don't get any notification, because the system can't be sure the comment is for you.

Comment: @Gimby take it easy, thanks God you are clever enough. I wrote that for aliens.

Comment: @Tom exactly, the system how detect that? I'm looking for that info

Comment: @MehdiDehghani I'm confused by what you are looking for.  Are you looking for a technical explanation of how things work?  Or a list of every situation that will trigger a notification?

Comment: @psubsee2003 best question here, both works for me, I think _every situation_ is the closest one

Comment: Besides the case you mention at the end of your question -which I address in my answer- are there other notifications or lack of notifications that intrigue you?

Comment: I'm sorry, which part of the question are you talking about?

Comment: The _"for example"_ bit, which is the only specific case you bring about. The rest of the triggers are quite specific and explicit, and explained in the post I linked.

Answer (score 5):

The general rules for notifications and pings are defined here:

- [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)
- [What events trigger an inbox notification?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319353/what-events-trigger-an-inbox-notification)

On top of this there is also:

If only one user comments on a post, and then the **post author** comments as well, the original user commenting will receive a notification, since the system will assume these two users are having a back-and-forth conversation.

If more users comment under that post, the system can no longer make that assumption, and you'll need to be explicitely "pinged" to get notifications.

(Which seems to me that's the part that's intriguing you, since these are the only "non-explicit" notification rules that I'm aware of).

Comment: I have been tring to find a post here on MSO to use as a dupe target, but can't find anything. All these posts are in MSE, apparently. Or my google-fu is very weak today.

Comment: So, you mentioned all the possibilities?

Comment: As far as I'm aware of. (Bonus points: you'll receive a notification for this comment, even if I'm not pinging you).